# Is there a GUI interface for sqlite?

Tags: windows, gui, sqlite, database

Is there a lightweight GUI interface for sqlite databases?  Preferably Windows based.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use [Sqliteman](http://sqliteman.com/).

[image]

Works on Windows and Linux.

Answer (score 5):

[SQLite Database Browser](http://sqlitebrowser.sourceforge.net/) is a good example.

[image]

There are also a bunch on [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1507506/what-are-good-open-source-gui-sqlite-database-managers). Sometimes it's a good idea to search there too, as using your computer often overlaps with programming it ;-).

Comment: The StackOverflow link is dead.

Answer (score 0):

If you are a Firefox user, there is [SQLite Manager](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/sqlite-manager/).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What about DB Browser?
http://sqlitebrowser.org/

For Windows and Mac (screenshot - dmg)
[image]